# wordpress site address is to a different site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I changed the site address in the settings of my wp page to a different site to see if it would send users to that specific page when they clicked the home banner. however it screwed everything up. Can i fix this in my ftp side of the house??

Comment: You will need to change `siteurl` and `home` values in your database http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: You can access your database via phpMyAdmin, although I'm not sure you can change it via FTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the file [**`wp-config.php`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php), located at the root of your WordPress installation and add the following lines:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yoursite.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursite.com' );
```

This assumes that your installation is in the root of the server. If it's installed in a folder, you have to adjust the address accordingly.