# How can I unconfuse my server between cjshayward.com and cshayward.com?

Tags: wordpress

I have separate Wordpress installations cjshayward.com and a present stub, cshayward.com. They are on the same host, with separate databases.

I would like to log in to cshayward.com, but when I load cshayward.com/wp-admin, it has the right title but the form action is cjshayward.com/wp-login.php. Whenever I try to log in to the present stub's administrative console, it bounces me to the other site.

I've tried deleting browsing history and using other browsers; I've looked in cshayward.com's wp-config.php to confirm no reference is stated to cjshayward.com, and I've looked through the Apache VirtualHost entry to confirm that HTTP connections are redirected to HTTPS and HTTPS refers to the files for the new site. Attempts to load cshayward.com/wp-admin redirect to https://cjshayward.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fcshayward.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 - on the old site, although the redirect URL is on the new site. The HTML is a mix of data from the old site and the new.

How can I unconfuse the installation so that attempts to load cshayward.com/wp-admin redirect correctly to the new present stub's login apparatus?

I can post non-private contents of wp-config data or query the database, but I do not presently know a reproducible way to log into the new site instead of the old, and looking at the config file plus Apache configuration has me drawing a near-blank.

The source for https://cshayward.com/wp-login.php pulls the title for the new site and specifies a form submission URL on the old site, and not the unchanged title for the old site, but specifies to send the old site a redirect URL on the new site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Log In &lsaquo; C.S. Hayward: A Guide to &quot;The Good Parts&quot; &#8212; WordPress</title>
    <meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large, noindex, noarchive' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='buttons-css'  href='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=5.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='forms-css'  href='https://cjshayward.com/wp-admin/css/forms.min.css?ver=5.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='l10n-css'  href='https://cjshayward.com/wp-admin/css/l10n.min.css?ver=5.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='login-css'  href='https://cjshayward.com/wp-admin/css/login.min.css?ver=5.9.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <meta name='referrer' content='strict-origin-when-cross-origin' />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        </head>
    <body class="login no-js login-action-login wp-core-ui  locale-en-us">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('no-js','js');
    </script>
        <div id="login">
        <h1><a href="https://wordpress.org/">Powered by WordPress</a></h1>
    
        <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://cjshayward.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="user_login">Username or Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" autocapitalize="off" />
            </p>

            <div class="user-pass-wrap">
                <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
                <div class="wp-pwd">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input password-input" value="" size="20" />
                    <button type="button" class="button button-secondary wp-hide-pw hide-if-no-js" data-toggle="0" aria-label="Show password">
                        <span class="dashicons dashicons-visibility" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
                        <p class="forgetmenot"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"  /> <label for="rememberme">Remember Me</label></p>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="https://cjshayward.com/wp-admin/" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
            </p>
        </form>

                    <p id="nav">
                                <a href="https://cjshayward.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Lost your password?</a>
            </p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
            function wp_attempt_focus() {setTimeout( function() {try {d = document.getElementById( "user_login" );d.focus(); d.select();} catch( er ) {}}, 200);}
wp_attempt_focus();
if ( typeof wpOnload === 'function' ) { wpOnload() }        </script>
                <p id="backtoblog">
            <a href="https://cjshayward.com/">&larr; Go to C.S. Hayward: A Guide to &quot;The Good Parts&quot;</a>      </p>
            </div>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2' id='jquery-migrate-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' id='zxcvbn-async-js-extra'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _zxcvbnSettings = {"src":"https:\/\/cjshayward.com\/wp-includes\/js\/zxcvbn.min.js"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/zxcvbn-async.min.js?ver=1.0' id='zxcvbn-async-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/regenerator-runtime.min.js?ver=0.13.9' id='regenerator-runtime-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.min.js?ver=3.15.0' id='wp-polyfill-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/dist/hooks.min.js?ver=1e58c8c5a32b2e97491080c5b10dc71c' id='wp-hooks-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/dist/i18n.min.js?ver=30fcecb428a0e8383d3776bcdd3a7834' id='wp-i18n-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' id='wp-i18n-js-after'>
wp.i18n.setLocaleData( { 'text direction\u0004ltr': [ 'ltr' ] } );
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' id='password-strength-meter-js-extra'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var pwsL10n = {"unknown":"Password strength unknown","short":"Very weak","bad":"Weak","good":"Medium","strong":"Strong","mismatch":"Mismatch"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' id='password-strength-meter-js-translations'>
( function( domain, translations ) {
    var localeData = translations.locale_data[ domain ] || translations.locale_data.messages;
    localeData[""].domain = domain;
    wp.i18n.setLocaleData( localeData, domain );
} )( "default", { "locale_data": { "messages": { "": {} } } } );
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter.min.js?ver=5.9.2' id='password-strength-meter-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js?ver=1.13.1' id='underscore-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' id='wp-util-js-extra'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpUtilSettings = {"ajax":{"url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"}};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js?ver=5.9.2' id='wp-util-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' id='user-profile-js-extra'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var userProfileL10n = {"user_id":"0","nonce":"1ddd65e585"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' id='user-profile-js-translations'>
( function( domain, translations ) {
    var localeData = translations.locale_data[ domain ] || translations.locale_data.messages;
    localeData[""].domain = domain;
    wp.i18n.setLocaleData( localeData, domain );
} )( "default", { "locale_data": { "messages": { "": {} } } } );
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cjshayward.com/wp-admin/js/user-profile.min.js?ver=5.9.2' id='user-profile-js'></script>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The "near" in near-blank is that the first, default HTTPS host in the Apache config is set to redirect to https://cjshayward.com, but this redirection should be an all or nothing deal. I can load the stub homepage from https://cshayward.com, so I don't think it is automatically redirecting; if that were happening, I'd expect a visit to the stub homepage to redirect to the original homepage, which isn't happening.

This is true after wiping and re-creating the database.

What is going on here?

Comment: You should list the plugins you have installed on each server.

Answer (score 0):

I read [wordpress site address is to a different site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471263/wordpress-site-address-is-to-a-different-site) and added to wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITE_URL', 'https://cshayward.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://cshayward.com');
```

That still had things confused, but when I dropped and re-created the database with these settings in place, it stopped bouncing me to controls for the other site.

**--UPDATE--**

This represents an incomplete resolution.

I was able, after making these changes, to get into cshayward.com/wp-admin itself and start editing a homepage. After 15 minutes or so the editor said my session had timed out and I needed to log in again, and the login redirected me to the login for cjshayward.com.

Now the editor appears to be up to old tricks.

More specifically, if I go to the "General Settings" panel, the "Wordpress Address (URL)" entry is cjshayward.com. Furthermore, if I change it to cshayward.com and click to save my changes, it displays a value of cjshayward.com that appears to be immune to change.

From the console:

```
MariaDB [cshayward]> update cs_options set option_value="https://cshayward.com" where option_name = "siteurl";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [cshayward]> select * from cs_options limit 1;
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name | option_value          | autoload |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
|         1 | siteurl     | https://cshayward.com | yes      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Then I reload the "General Settings" page and the option value is changed back.

```
MariaDB [cshayward]> select * from cs_options limit 1;
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name | option_value           | autoload |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+----------+
|         1 | siteurl     | https://cjshayward.com | yes      |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

**--ADDITIONAL UPDATE--**

I had an advanced-cache.php from a copied plugin.

I have moved out all plugins except for classic editor and widgets. I do not detect any change in behavior.

**--FURTHER ADDITIONAL UPDATE--**

I've tried tearing down and rebuilding the site several times (including at least some of the time wiping the database as well as wiping the Wordpress installation), and have gotten apparent success for the time, but the behavior reappears.

I've added the classic editor for posts and widgets to wp-content/plugins, and twentysixteen and twentysixteen-ux-tweaks-child (the latter is the active theme at https://cjshayward.com) to wp-content/themes, and nothing else. Earlier I had a caching plugin that could have accounted to observed changes, but that has never been at the current build. Adding the definitions advocated at [wordpress site address is to a different site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471263/wordpress-site-address-is-to-a-different-site) has not changed behavior with the current site.